# how to browse my DataBase records on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using Heroku for my Ruby on Rails app. 
Is there any good tool for browsing my database records? and modify it?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an addon for a db console in heroku. It's not official, but I think it is made by the heroku team anyhow. See https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console

Comment: I am using is, very nice tool.